# SearchView with Recycler View not working in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make the connection between adapter and fragment, but I get the following error when I try to filter the data for SearchView: Function invocation 'filter(...)' expected. As now I am learning Android, any input will be helpful for me. Thank you!

```
class RecyclerViewFragment : Fragment() {
private var adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val searchIcon = country_search.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.search_mag_icon)
    searchIcon.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE)

    val cancelIcon = country_search.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.search_close_btn)
    cancelIcon.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE)

    val textView = country_search.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.search_src_text)
    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
    searchCountry(country_search)

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_view, container, false)
}

private fun searchCountry(search: SearchView) {
    search.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            adapter.filter.filter(newText)
            adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            return true
        }

    })

  } 

}
```

Error log:

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline fun <T> Array<out TypeVariable(T)>.filter(predicate: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Boolean): List<TypeVariable(T)> defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun BooleanArray.filter(predicate: (Boolean) -> Boolean): List<Boolean> defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun ByteArray.filter(predicate: (Byte) -> Boolean): List<Byte> defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun CharArray.filter(predicate: (Char) -> Boolean): List<Char> defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun CharSequence.filter(predicate: (Char) -> Boolean): CharSequence defined in kotlin.text
public inline fun DoubleArray.filter(predicate: (Double) -> Boolean): List<Double> defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun FloatArray.filter(predicate: (Float) -> Boolean): List<Float> defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun IntArray.filter(predicate: (Int) -> Boolean): List<Int> defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun LongArray.filter(predicate: (Long) -> Boolean): List<Long> defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun ShortArray.filter(predicate: (Short) -> Boolean): List<Short> defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun String.filter(predicate: (Char) -> Boolean): String defined in kotlin.text
public inline fun UByteArray.filter(predicate: (UByte) -> Boolean): List<UByte> defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun UIntArray.filter(predicate: (UInt) -> Boolean): List<UInt> defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun ULongArray.filter(predicate: (ULong) -> Boolean): List<ULong> defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun UShortArray.filter(predicate: (UShort) -> Boolean): List<UShort> defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.filter(predicate: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Boolean): List<TypeVariable(T)> defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.filter(predicate: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Boolean): Map<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)> defined in kotlin.collections
public fun <T> Sequence<TypeVariable(T)>.filter(predicate: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Boolean): Sequence<TypeVariable(T)> defined in kotlin.sequences
```

Comment: Share the log please.

Comment: What does `adapter.filter` refer to? Also it should probably be `adapter?.filter`, it probably won't compile without some sort of null assertion.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of your RecyclerView? Specifically the filter function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few things wrong with this code.
If you would try and follow these steps (can be done in in onCreateView).

1. Init the recyclerview that is associated with this layout.
   RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
2. Init the adapter that you would like to link with this recyclerview.
   adapter = new MyAwesomeAdapter(myAwesomeCountryList);
3. Add the adapter to the recyclerview.
   recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
4. Adding a layoutmanager to the recyclerview.
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)

If you have done that, you are quite close (hopefully it solves it but there are more things we can not see, such as how you set up your associated layout).